# Oracle performance issue with massive inserts and truncates (AWR attached)

Tags: performance, oracle, insert, truncate

I'm using Oracle to synchronize events between two nodes of my application server (never mind why/if that's the best way/etc. This is a given).

To do so, I'm using an "events" table that one node (the "active") writes new events to and the other node (the "passive") reads from. The table looks like:

Event UUID (UUID) || Event ID (long)  ||  Event Data (several columns of different types)

The event ID is a number constantly increasing (application controlled, not a sequence) that signifies the revision the internal model would be at after applying the event data. The Event UUID has unique constraint. I have a single index on the event ID to facilitate the select SQL - "Select ... where Event_ID > XXX order by Event_ID" where the XXX is the internal revision number of the passive node. Once in a while I truncate the table (using "truncate reuse storage").
[Actually, I use three such tables in a round-robin order so I could always truncate the one I'm about to write to the my passive node can have time to "catch up"].

After several hours of inserting and truncating where everything is fine I start getting a lot of "noise" from the database and response time drops dramatically. This can go on for an hour or two (or even more), then all of the sudden it stops and response time return to its normal level. The AWR reports point toward the truncate statement and a bit toward the insert statements. I suspect something is going on with DBWR - but I can't pinpoint. Note that this performance degradation happens even when the secondary node (the one running the "SELECT" statements) is off - so it's pure insert/truncate. Note2: This issue does NOT reproduce on MSSQL.

**The question**: why is this happening? What can I do to stop it? Are there alternatives to this design (the closer the alternative to the current design the better).

Update 1: I might have mislead with the title. This is not a single massive insert but a trickle of inserts as the events are generated in the application server.

Update 2: AWR compare of a sample from the first period (good) and the second period (bad) is at http://pastehtml.com/view/1eirn20.html

Update 3: new AWR diff at http://pastehtml.com/view/1eirn20.html

**Update 4: *Solved*. Apparently it WAS the storage (thanks ik_zelf!). Just goes to show - abstractions aren't really abstract. At the end, it's a magnetized spinning plate.**

Comment: @Ran Biron are there any indexes on the table - because these should be disabled before mass inserts etc

Comment: @Rob: this is not a mass insert - but a trickle insert. I'll update the question.

Comment: Can you post the AWR report for an interval where performance is slow and an interval where performance is fast?

Comment: @Ran Biron: what is the config like? (archivelog, standbydb, when run backups, are concurrent users active)?

Comment: @Justin - might be able to (have to ask my boss - sensitive information and so forth) - but Monday at the earliest.

Comment: @ik_zelf: This is a performance testing DB - no HA, so no archive log / standby / backups. Concurrent users - ranging from none to 20-30, but all are application users, but on these table we have only a single transaction at a time doing inserts and, once every five minutes, another one doing the truncate.

Comment: @Ran Biron: is the system shared by other applications/databases? Same for storage? Could, for example, backups of the others influence your performance?

Comment: @ik_zelf: system is not shared - it's dedicated to the test.

Comment: Is the storage also dedicated? (what kind?)

Comment: @ik_zelf - storage may be problematic - but I'll need a hard fact (from my logs) to justify looking into it.

Comment: Is a variation of a factor 2 in io times enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the awr reports is a clear indication that the io time doubles in the bad period compared to the first period. Check the storage usage. It could very well be that the storage is shared between systems and that - for example - an other system is taking a backup and causes a bad period. Check the logs of all connected systems/backups an try to connect the times to your test findings.

Comment: Apparently (after a lot of back-and-forth) storage WAS the issue. Thanks for the tip, it really helped.

Comment: :-D In many cases SAN's are considered as a storage consolidation solution but not designed for performance..... Glad it helped.