# Oracle performance drop in massive table copy

Tags: oracle, database-administration

Situation:
I'm using Oracle 11g R2 to work on two database users.

User U0 = original database with hundreds of tables
User U1 = copy of U0 to be used for simulating U0

To maintain U1, I run a script as below on U1 when simulation starts.

```
    truncate table T1;  
    truncate table T2;  
    ...  
    insert into T1 (select * from U0.T1)  
    insert into T2 (select * from U0.T2)  
    ...
```

Problem: It had no problem for few days, but got slower after weeks.
Also it sometimes stop inserting records in tables, and in this case it always stops at same table. However I don't think that the table size is the problem since it has less than 20,000 records only.

I guess that this is due to resource problem in DBMS side, disk or memory, but have no idea how to resolve it. I could find a similar question as below without exact procedure to work around storage problem. Maybe this can be simple one to DBAs but unfortunately I'm not qualified for that.

[Oracle performance issue with massive inserts and truncates (AWR attached)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993251/oracle-performance-issue-with-massive-inserts-and-truncates-awr-attached)

Edit: following Jon Heller's comment, I've got query results as follows.

1. dba_resumable : no records.
2. gv$sql : 5~6 records queried but insert statement is not included.
   Most notable one is "select TIME_WAITED_MICRO from V$SYSTEM_EVENT  where event = 'Shared IO Pool Memory'". I guess it is due to insufficient memory.
3. report_sql_monitor : every sql_id returns "SQL Monitoring Report" without additional information.

Edit2: Please forget about edit above. Insert statement appeared in gv$sql query and SQL monitor result is as attached picture.
[image: SQL Monitoring Report]

Edit3: This time SQL monitor returned Activity detail for the same insert statement.
[image: SQL Monitoring Report 2]

Comment: after each insert are you freeing memory by using commit?

Comment: I expect it would get slower and slower if you don't commit the changes.

Comment: It is potentially IO issue. You need to see whether there is slower IO on the database file in which table resides. You might have to work with your storage team or system admin team,

Comment: Find out what the slow queries are waiting on.  If the database is completely out of a resource like temporary tablespace, the query may be suspended and it will show up in `select * from dba_resumable;`.  If it's just slowing down, find the slow SQL statement with a query like this: `select * from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`.  Then plug the SQL_ID into this to find out which operation is slow and what it's waiting on: `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'XYZ') from dual;`.  Add the entire results of the last query to the question.

Comment: The "Activity Detail" is empty, which is unusual.  This implies that the time is being spent on a recursive query.  This can happen when there's a strange problem with the data dictionary, an unusual object that causes dynamic sampling queries to run poorly, or a PL/SQL object that calls other slow queries.  You need to repeat the process of looking at GV$SQL and SQL Monitoring.  This time you're looking for another query, perhaps run by a different user, that is running for about the same ELAPSED_TIME.  It may help to `alter system flush shared_pool;` to reset the timers.

Comment: If this is just for test purposes, then try setting the target tables to NOLOGGING and use direct path insert instead of conventional. This can also be more efficient at maintaining indexes during a load, but make sure you have plenty of TEMP space.

Comment: Thank you for comments. I'm using auto-commit, nologging, and direct path insert already, but the problem still exists.

Comment: "LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL" and the absence of an APPEND hint indicate that you're not using direct path, and if you're not using direct path then you're are logging the insert. Do you have different monitor results for a direct path insert?

Comment: In the last picture append hint is applied in the insert SQL. Also I altered the table in user U1 as nologging before capturing the screen. I'm afraid of missing something because it is my first try for direct path.

Comment: Direct-path writes have many limitations.  For example, triggers and foreign keys will prevent them.  A trigger with a slow SQL statement may explain the lack of "Activity Detail".  Normally there should be about one sample per second.  If there's only 2 per 347 seconds then most of the time is being spent elsewhere, probably on some recursive query.

Comment: Sorry for being off topic for long time. After disabling all triggers on the user resulted expected performance. Really thank you for pinpointing advice.